# Twitter API Timeout

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to develop a application integrating Twitter API and collect all followers and their tweets but in some point Twitter gives timeout and wont work till next day. Is there any solution for this problem

Comment: probably a usage limit, which resets each day. In other words, twitter doesn't want you to scrape twitter.

Comment: Is there any way to overcome this problem...???

Comment: @doubleD can you update your question with a programming language tag? it might help you get more relevant answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API has rate limits on the number of requests you can make in a given time. The details are on their dev site:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

You need to stay within these limits.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use PHP? In my case, I added this code above the error line of code and it worked.

set_time_limit(600);